# Details on EE 2.7.0 Markdown Plugin and field format

Tags: add-on, plugin, core, 2.7.0, markdown

Looking at the Changelogs for EE 2.7.0 I see there is now:

`Added Markdown plugin and field formatting option`

…but I don't see any details in the documentation. Is there any information available on the new plug-in and how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the plugin file in EE 2.7:

This plugin parses text using Markdown and Smartypants. To use this plugin wrap
any text in this tag pair:

```
{exp:markdown}
Text to be **parsed**.
{/exp:markdown}
```

There are two parameters you can set:

- encode_ee_tags - ('yes'/'no') defaults to 'yes', when set to 'no' allows EE 
  code to be rendered
- smartypants - ('yes'/'no') defaults to 'yes', when set to 'no' stops 
  SmartyPants from running which leaves your quotes and hyphens alone

---

For basic syntax, EE is referring to http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Also, PHP Markdown is being used, so anything you see here -- http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/ -- is available. Good for adding classes and ids, etc.

Comment: Stephen, you can set the format of field as Markdown, too, and to not use the `exp:markdown`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right, I remember reading that in the blog post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. What we really need is a way to allow our authors to write in Markdown and then use that to insert into EE when adding a new channel entry. Basically a streamlined workflow. The way we have to do it now is to write the MD and then export the XHTML and copy paste that into EE's channel entry field.